# Optimise 3D placement of rooms?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic, genetic-algorithm, heuristics

Given a graph where the nodes represent 3x3x1 rooms and the vertices represent a need for closeness. How should they be placed in 3D space to optimise overall closeness?

Example (randomish) datastructure:

```
{
    room1: [room2, room3],
    room2: [room1, room4],
    room3: [room5],
    room4: [room2, room5, room1],
    room5: []
}
```

(I'm not exactly sure where I should be asking this question as it's different from most I see on stackoverflow. I am interested in programming solutions/heuristic algorithms.)

Comment: How do you compute the closeness of two rooms? Is it the minimal distance between two blocks? What norm are you using?

Comment: Practically, I'm planning on applying this to design a Dwarf Fortress layout. Currently I want to know how it's done in general before I start thinking of stairways and rooms of different dimensions. The closeness is best characterised by distance between room centres.

Comment: (Hmm, *Chebyshev distance between room centres)

Comment: Upvote: best application of algorithms I've seen this year.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want adjacency.

In a [backtracking search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking), maintain a queue of rooms ordered by how many other rooms they are connected to in the graph (the most constrained variable heuristic). Then, for each room in the queue:

- determine the possible grid positions it can take and pick one of them;
- in a loop, determine whether any other rooms exist which now can only be in one spot, put them there and remove them from the queue ([forward checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-ahead_%28backtracking%29));
- if any of the previous steps failed, backtrack to the last choice point (undo the changes to the grid).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to read up about this. If adjacency isn't possible, i.e. there is a central room that needs to be close to too many other rooms. Would a backtracking search be able to find the layout the overall closest rooms?

Comment: Not the algorithm that I sketched; adding such "preference constraints" can mean you have to radically change the problem representation before applying backtracking search. Check out [Russell & Norvig](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), chapter 6 in the 3rd edition.

Answer (score 2):

Smells like a far cousin of a 3D [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), which is NP-complete. Try construction heuristics (first fit, best fit decreasing, ...) followed by metaheuristics (Tabu search, simulated annealing, genetic algorithms, ...).
There is open source software out there for that, such as [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner), openTS, jgap, ...